# How does shining, n, lasers of same or differing wavelengths at a small area increase the power at that area?

Tags: photons, laser, laser-interaction

Is the effect of added lasers simply additive? Is there experimental evidence to confirm, or could someone refer me to this? If definitely seems obvious but I can't assume

Comment: If there is not interference (which requires the same wavelength) then it is additive. You can easily calculate it by adding two sinus wave and integrating their sum sqare.

Comment: Is there experimental evidence to confirm, or could someone refer me to this? If definitely seems obvious but I can't assume

Comment: It is a trivial thing. It is like asking, "is there an experimental evidence that trown stones are flying a parabolic curve". However, I am not a physicist. They likely can give you more convincing info about this, but you didn't ask. We can't see your mind, we can see only what you literally ask. Check other questions on the site, check their size. Roughly this size and detailedness (i.e. explain, what you want to know, *in details*) will get the best results (i.e. real answers from real physicists).

Comment: Actually no, it's not trivial or else I wouldn't have asked it... Also projectile motion is an approximation (air resistance? Temperature? Angular momentum?) and is an ideal situation (aka not reality). Now I am not quite sure how more descriptive I should be. Quite simply are lasers additive. Now you can talk about interference but I make it clear I want the power on an area. Thanks for the comment though at least you have some respect!

Comment: Edit reverted; [please be nice](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: Does the "to downvote you need to comment" feature exist here? Clearly there's major barriers to entry for newcomers and I'm not the first. "Be nice" ;).   https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/can-i-tell-who-downvoted-one-of-my-answers https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes

Comment: @AustinNguyen: No, there's no comment requirement for downvotes and as the link you provided suggested, it's not ever going to happen.

Answer (score 0):

may be I got your question. Please correct me if I am wrong. So what you want to know basically is that suppose you have two lasers and you made them fall at the same point say over a screen, then what would be the power delivered to the screen, will it remain same or it will get doubled or the addition is something different (like when we add resistances in parallel and in series, the addition are of different types).

From the definition of power we know that power is the work done per unit time , so now when you made the lasers to fall on a screen, say the energy of  the two lasers are different (depending upon their frequencies), since energy is always additive, i guess the power will also be additive.

Comment: Yes! Thankyou. That's what I would guess too, but is it true? I'm looking for reality or potential complications not some textbook ideal case if that's possible